# Scala collections

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi Can any one please help me on the below query.
I am working on a scala code where I have a Scala collections list 'students' as shown below.

```
List(
  students(Rajesh,  21, branch1, sem1), 
  students(Kamal,   25, branch2, sem2),
  students(Kavitha, 23, branch3, sem3)
)
```

Here students is the case class like

```
case class students(name:String, age:Int, branchname:String, semname: String)
```

Now my requirement is to get the name for a particular branch. How can i get that.

I can convert the Scala list students into dataframe using `.toDF()` and write the where conditions to read the appropriate row and get the value.

But since the data is very small for me in this case so I want to use purely scala collections `List`.

Can anyone please help on the same.

Comment: Clarify, please, what the result for this example data should look like. Do you want to get a list of students' names on a given branch? Also, is Spark really related here? If you want a solution without it, just remove it from the question, it will make it easier to understand.

Comment: I am able to fix it with the below approach.

Comment: The Scala list I have assigned to a variable "studentsList", then I am able to iterate through it.                                                                                                                `studentsList.foreach(x => func(x.name, x.age, x. branch, x.sem))

def func(name: String, age: Int, branch: String, sem: String): Unit = {
println(name)
println(age)
println(branch)
}`

Answer (score 3):

your question does not mention why spark is required, you could do this all very easily as follows, assuming  your case class is defines the same

```
case class students(name: String, age: Int, branch: String, sem: String)

val listStudents = List(students("Rajesh",21,"branch1","sem1"),
    students("Kamal",25,"branch2","sem2"),students("Kavitha",23,"branch3","sem3"))

val filteredNames = listStudents.filter(_.branch == "branch2").map(_.name)
```